# Accessing a specific dictionary inside a dictionary - Django Templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have the following "example" dictionary

```
myDict = {obj1:{key_a1:value_a1, key_a2:value_a2, key_a3:value_a3} , 
          obj2:{key_b1:value_b1, key_b2:value_b2, key_b3:value_b3} ,
          obj3:{key_c1:value_c1, key_c2:value_c2, key_c3:value_c3} }
```

Where obj are some class objects.

What if I just want to iterate over the values belonging to key obj2 only, how would I do that inside a template?

I've tried

```
{% for node,manyResults in myDict[obj2].items %}
//Error: Could not parse the remainder: '[obj2].items' from 'dict[obj2].items'
```

and

```
{% for node,manyResults in myDict[obj2] %}
//Error: Could not parse the remainder: '[obj2]' from 'dict[obj2]'
```

and

```
{% for node,manyResults in myDict.obj2.items %}  
//OR
{% for node,manyResults in myDict.obj2 %}
//Both no error, but the values don't appear
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Just so I understand, you actually have the literal model instance as the key? Don't key by anything but strings, or you'll shoot yourself in the foot in one way or another. Here, it's that there's no possible way for the the template tag to pull the key out of the context, because it would need to be literally passed the instance, which you can't do in the template.

Comment: More specifically, this is not *too* much of a problem in general in Python because of it's duck-typing, but in a first-level language like C++, Java, etc., where things are only equal if they point at exactly the same piece of memory, doing this would be disasterous. Just because Python is a little more lax, doesn't mean you should use shoddy programming practices.

Comment: What django version are you using?

Comment: @ChrisPratt I'll think about how I can redesign this then. Would it work if they were strings?

Comment: @Francisco - The latest and greatest, 1.4.1

Comment: Yes, if they were strings then your third listed method will work. The first two will never work no matter what.

Comment: What does '{{myDict.obj1.key_a1}}' inside the for loop show?

Comment: I believe you can use 2 nested for loops, if the structure is constant. like `{% for key, item in myDict.items %} {% for innerkey, inneritem in item.items %}....` doesn't it fix your problem?

Comment: @PratikMandrekar - I never get inside the for-loop =/

Comment: @Francisco Yes, that would, but I only need the second key,value set, not all of them. (in this specific instance. Of course, I do end up using all of them)

Comment: @Dana I don't see why this should be a problem. You will have to iterarate over your data structure anyway, I don't believe there's a "shortcut" for this kind of iteration, if that's what you are looking for. And even if there was one, behind the scenes it would look pretty much how I've written it, I think. Iteration is a limited operation inside Django templates. Doing this is already a victory. Back in the past I wrote a templatetag to index dictionaries in my template ;)

Comment: @Francisco But I don't want to iterate over all of them. They must each be called in different part of the website. But from all this above discussion, it seems that it can't really be done =/

Comment: Can you just try printing {{myDict.obj1.key_a1}} outside the for loop?

Comment: @Dana Ah, I see now. In this case, maybe you are just complicating things. If those 3 dicts are all you'll need, I would add them separetelly to my context dict and use'em independently in the template.

Comment: @PratikMandrekar Nothing appears =/

Comment: Does it work in pure python code? Try in the console to loop over the data you have. Also what kind of objects are these?  Maybe the data is really empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way of doing this with Django templates, and that you should do as I said in my comments, which I'll rewrite here -- with some edits -- to summarize the hole thing up.

--

Maybe you are just complicating things. If those 3 dicts are all you'll need, I would add them separetelly to my context dict and use'em independently in the template.

You can also iterate over them as I said:

```
{% for key, item in myDict.items %}
    {% for innerkey, inneritem in item.items %}
        ...
```

Also, your last example would work if 'objX' were strings, because django templates can map that. Otherwise, it would simply not find the identifier in its namespace (as you have realized).

Hope it helps.